# How to get the interface orientation when the device orientation is faceDown or faceUp?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm setting the orientation for `AVCaptureVideoOrientation` by getting the current device orientation, however I'm having trouble to get the interface orientation when the device is faceDown or faceUp. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
private func configureDeviceOrientation() {
    var videoOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation {
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
        case .faceUp, .faceDown:
            //I don't know whether the interface orientation is landscapeLeft
            //or landscapeRight nor do I know how to check.
    }
}
```

**`interfaceOrientation` is deprecated from iOS 8 and this is a framework, therefore I don't have access to `UIApplication.shared`**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my `AVCaptureVideoOrientation`.

Just use `self.view.window?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation` in place of `UIDevice.current.orientation`:

```
switch self.view.window?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation {
    case .portrait:
        previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
    case .portraitUpsideDown:
        previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
    case .landscapeRight:
        previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
    case .landscapeLeft:
        previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
    default:
        print("other")
}
```

This value will be either portrait, portraitUpsideDown, landscapeRight, or landscapeLeft.

Call this code on startup and every time the device changes orientation.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3198088-interfaceorientation) for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Add to viewWillAppear to check if device is rotated:

```
   //Observer for if Device Rotated
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(device_rotated),
                                            name:UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification,
                                               object: nil)
```

Add to viewWillDisappear:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```

Add to viewController.  Function will be called if device is rotated or orientation changed:

```
@objc func device_rotated(notification:Notification) -> Void{

    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    case .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight:
        print("Landscape")
    case .portrait, .portraitUpsideDown:
        print("Portrait")
    case .faceUp:
        print("Face Up")
    case .faceDown:
        print("Face Down")
    default:
        print("Default")
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you check the interface orientation while it’s being `faceDown` or `faceUp`?

Comment: If you add the code that I wrote above, then whenever you rotate your device it will tell you the orientation.  So if the orientation is faceDown or faceUp then the case .faceUp and case .faceDown lines of the switch statement will be called.  Is that not working for you?  It works when I test it on my device.